# mutate combining multiple conditions - R dyplr

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have the following first rows of a dataframe :

```
response_accuracy = data.frame (trial_number  = c("108", "108", "108", "108","108",
                                                  "108", "111", "111", "111", "111",
                                                  "111", "111","112", "112","112",
                                                  "112","112", "112"),
                                response_time_to_origine = c("19516.990", "19516.990",
                                                             "19516.990", "19516.990",
                                                             "19516.990", "19516.990",
                                                             "21364.9990", "21364.990",
                                                             "21364.9990", "21364.990",
                                                             "21364.9990", "21364.990",
                                                             "22068.990", "22068.990",
                                                             "22068.990", "22068.990",
                                                             "22068.990", "22068.990"),
                                block = c("1","1","2","2","3","3", "1","1","2","2",
                                          "3","3","1","1","2","2","3","3"),
                                subblock = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B",
                                             "A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B",
                                             "A","B"),
                                target_onset = c("18893.7100", "1299.7971", 
                                                 "4802.5891", "16355.1118",
                                                 "18766.6272", "24800.6479",
                                                 "20717.6990", "7688.3330",
                                                 "15868.4771", "16355.1118",
                                                 "23899.7302", "16067.6699",
                                                 "20717.6990", "27016.7981",
                                                 "23333.1860", "23083.0769",
                                                 "18766.6272", "16067.6699"),
                                target_onset_plus200 = c("19093.7100","1499.7971",
                                                         "5002.5891", "16555.1118", 
                                                         "18966.6272","25000.6479", 
                                                         "20917.6990","7888.3330", 
                                                         "16068.4771","16555.1118",
                                                         "24099.7302","16267.6699",
                                                         "20917.6990","27216.7981",
                                                         "23533.1860","23283.0769",
                                                         "18966.6272","16267.6699"), 
                                target_onset_plus1000 = c("19893.710","2299.797",
                                                          "5802.589","17355.112",
                                                          "19766.627","25800.648",
                                                          "21717.699","8688.333",
                                                          "16868.477","17355.112", 
                                                          "24899.730","17067.670",
                                                          "21717.699","28016.798",
                                                          "24333.186","24083.077",
                                                          "19766.627","17067.670"))
```

Now, I would like to know whether, for each trial_number, the value in response_time_to_origin is contained between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000 but according to multiple conditions :

if 76 <= trial_number <= 151, filter block == 1 and subblock == "A" and then check whether response_time_to_origin is between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000. If so answer TRUE, if this happens for other blocks and subblock, answer FALSE.

else if 152 <= trial_number <= 227, filter block == 1 and subblock == "B" and then check whether response_time_to_origin is between target_onset_plus200 and target_onset_plus1000. If so answer TRUE, if this happens for other blocks and subblock, answer FALSE.

ETC.

I have tried to insert the following bit of code, which obviously does not work :

```
response_accuracy=data_out%>%     
   select(trial_number, response_time_to_origin)%>%     
   filter(!is.na(response_time_to_origin))%>%     
   mutate(list_windows_terminals = list(list_hit_windows))%>%      
   unnest(list_windows_terminals)%>%     
   group_by(block, subblock, trial_number)%>%     
   mutate(response_in_window = if(76 <= trial_number <= 151){     
      filter(block == 1 & subblock == "A") & response_time_to_origin >      
      target_onset_plus200 & response_time_to_origin < 
      target_onset_plus1000)})
```

And neither does this one :

```
response_accuracy=data_out%>%
    select(trial_number, response_time_to_origin)%>%
    filter(!is.na(response_time_to_origin))%>%
    mutate(list_windows_terminals = list(list_hit_windows))%>% 
    unnest(list_windows_terminals)%>%
    group_by(block, subblock, trial_number)%>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 76, 151) && block == 1 && subblock == "A", "TRUE", "FALSE")) %>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 152, 227) && block == 1 && subblock == "B", "TRUE", "FALSE"))%>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 228, 303) && block == 2 && subblock == "A", "TRUE", "FALSE")) %>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 304, 379) && block == 2 && subblock == "B", "TRUE", "FALSE"))%>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 380, 455) && block == 3 && subblock == "A", "TRUE", "FALSE")) %>%
    mutate(response_in_window = ifelse(between(trial_number, 456, 531) && block == 3 && subblock == "B", "TRUE", response_in_window))
```

Could you help me ? Thanks a lot in advance :

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case_when to build up the logic for each of your conditions. See example below with your first condition included. You can add the other conditions as new lines in your case_when statement.

```
output <- response_accuracy %>%
  mutate(response_time_to_origine = as.numeric(response_time_to_origine),
         target_onset_plus200 = as.numeric(target_onset_plus200),
         target_onset_plus1000 = as.numeric(target_onset_plus1000),
         trial_number = as.numeric(trial_number),
         block = as.numeric(block),
         target_onset = as.numeric(target_onset)) %>%
  mutate(Flag1 = ifelse(response_time_to_origine > target_onset_plus200 & 
                          response_time_to_origine < target_onset_plus1000, 
                        T, F),
         answer = 
           case_when(
             Flag1 & trial_number >76 & trial_number < 151 & block == 1 & subblock == "A" ~ "Meets Conditions",
             T ~ "Does Not Meet Conditions"
           ))
```